# Launch my Mac app in case other Mac app was launched

Tags: objective-c, macos, process

I need to write Mac app which will start automatically only in case when another particular app was launched. Could you please provide entry point where to look and what to use. Do I need to have special autostart up process? I am new to Mac app development.

Comment: Where is launched another particular app?

Comment: Launched as simple Mac apps like Preview, Messages or other installed apps from the App Store.

Comment: Use ApplScript to monitor the status of each application.

Comment: @ElTomato Thanks for it. AppleScript it self cannot listen for apps/process which was started. If I am wrong correct me.

Comment: Use NSTimer to check application statuses every x seconds.

Comment: Is not to expensive for OS to run timer lets say every 10 sec? Is here no another way to do it. Let say to add observer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add observer using `CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter()` for example.
Please, take a look at this article, here may be the solution [Inter-process communication](http://nshipster.com/inter-process-communication/)